# complex exponential equation $e^{jz\pi}+j=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Which are the solutions of this equation?

> $e^{jz\pi}+j=0$

i was using the formula

> $\cos(...)+j\sin(...)$
>   but it gives wrong results... I can't understand how to get it step by step

Comment: Can you edit your answer to show what you did with the formula to get the wrong results? That might help us get a better idea of where you went wrong.

Comment: i made similar steps to @gimuli but i get 3/2+2k , but this way i miss the -1/2 solution...

Comment: @xmaionx Note that we have  $-\frac12+2k, \frac32+2h, \frac52+2m$ and so on are all equivalent solutions

Comment: @xmaionx show your work and effort in the OP in order to avoid downvotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that

$$-j=e^{j\left(\frac{3\pi}2+2k\pi\right)}$$

therefore

$$e^{jz\pi}+j=0 \iff e^{jz\pi}=-j=e^{j\left(\frac{3\pi}2+2k\pi\right)}$$

that is

$$z\pi=\frac{3\pi}2+2k\pi \implies z=\frac{3}2+2k \quad k\in \mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: i get to that but this way don't you miss the -1/2 ? cause this is part from  an integral and -1/2 it's a pole so this would change

Comment: @xmaionx we dont loose solutions since for $k=-1$ we have $-\frac12=\frac32+2\cdot (-1)$.

Comment: isn't k only positive numbers ?

Comment: @xmaionx $k$ is an integer that is $k\in \mathbb{Z}=\{0,\pm 1,\pm 2, \ldots\}$

Comment: Note that the numbers called $k$ in line two and line three are possibly different. (or the first and second lines are "for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$" while the third is "there exists a $k\in\mathbb{Z}$"). It does not matter for the calculation here, though.

Answer (score 1):

You have to solve $e^{jz\pi}=-j$. Now $-j=e^{-j\pi/2}$ and $e^a=e^b$ if and only if $a-b=2k\pi j$ for an integer $k$. Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that $e^a=e^b$ if and only if $a=b+2\pi k i$ for integral $k$.

Put your equation in this form as follows:

$$e^{iz\pi} + i=0$$
$$e^{iz\pi}=-i$$
$$e^{iz\pi}=e^{-\pi i/2}\tag{since $-i$ can be written as $e^{-\pi i/2}$}$$
So this is true if and only if

$$iz\pi = -\pi i/2 + 2\pi ki = \pi i(2k - \tfrac12)$$
$$\boxed{z = 2k-\tfrac12}$$
for integral $k$. These are the values
$$\left\{\ldots, -\frac92, -\frac52,-\frac12,\frac32,\frac72,\frac{11}2,\ldots \right\}$$